# Wild card subdomain of subdomain in apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, domain, subdomain

currently I have worked wildcard subdomain config like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.domain
    ErrorLog /tmp/error.log
    CustomLog /tmp/access.log combined
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/public
<Directory "/var/www">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but if I enter sub.sub.domain will return to default vhost. how to configure to the main/root domain's path? I tried below conf but still not worked:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.*.domain
    ErrorLog /tmp/error.log
    CustomLog /tmp/access.log combined
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2/public
<Directory "/var/www">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I changed %2 to %1 still doesn't work.

What is right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After workaround for some hours, actually above code have right syntax but I just put it to the wrong placement order. So the correct answer is put the second one to the top above the first one.

Below full config example :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.*.domain
    ErrorLog /tmp/error.log
    CustomLog /tmp/access.log combined
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2/public
<Directory "/var/www">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.domain
    ErrorLog /tmp/error.log
    CustomLog /tmp/access.log combined
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/public
<Directory "/var/www">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache is skip the same subdomain/domain config by ascending order from the top. sub.sub.domain is also a part of *.domain , so if I want to configure it I must put the config in the top or if use different file config use lower number name.